# Can a port both render page and return data in Express

Tags: node.js, express, backend

Says we have a personal blog page, once the user visit '/home', the server returns all the blog posts he has written, meanwhile I also want to get data from the server so I can handle the data with template in front-end. In Express, is there any way to perform action like this:

```
app.get('/home', function () {
  Post
    .getAll()
    .then(function (posts) {
      res.send(posts)
    })

  res.render('home')
})
```

The reason I want to do this is to minimal ports and also gathering them up by functionalities, or have I define data-ports for each one?

Thanks 4 help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that. Separate your data and template providing logic like this sample:

```
app.get('/home', function () {
  res.render('home');
});

app.get('/api/posts', function () {
  Post
    .getAll()
    .then(function (posts) {
      res.send(posts);
    });
});
```

Comment: Absolutely right, I saw my colleague doing so who's using php